# .NET Core Web API Debug/Publish difference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I dont know how explain my problem. I have difference at publish and debug. I got simple Post Method it's working on Debug. ex:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("Auth/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthenticateController : ControllerBase
{
    private IAuthService _authService;

    public AuthenticateController(IAuthService authService)
    {
        _authService = authService;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]ConnectModel connect)
    {
        var _authModel = _authService.Authenticate(connect);

        return await Task.Run(() => Ok(_authModel));
    }
}
```

[Working on Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlrlo.png)

and this post method doesnt work at IIS. ex:

[Doesn't Work at IIS Https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyjQX.png)

[Doesn't Work at IIS Http](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0593.png)

What should I do ? Am I missing something ? Thx for help.

Comment: Did you install the ASP.NET Core/.NET Core : Runtime & Hosting Bundle? Follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#iis-configuration)

Comment: Side note, instead of returning `Task.Run`, do `return await Task.FromResult(Ok(_authModel))`

Comment: This code doesn't do anything asynchronously so there's no reason to use `Task.Run` or `async/await` at all. In any case there's no reason to start another thread only to return a value that's already available. It's `Authenticate` that could benefit from asynchronous operation but *not* `Task.Run`.

Comment: As it is, change the return type to `IActionResult` and just `return Ok(_authModel);`. Each HTTP request is already served by a separate thread so there's no benefit in calling `Authenticate` from another thread with `Task.Run`.

Comment: @Thangadurai Yes its already been installed.

Comment: @FCin ty for side note.

Comment: If you add a new method in `AuthenticateController`, with `return Ok("Test");`, will it work? You could try to debug your project from VS with hosting in IIS.